# flexigrid how to access url posted parameters when they are sent to script

Tags: php, jquery

Edit to answer:

I have tried the following

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess (function(ev, xhr, s) {
    document.write('url: ' + s.data);
});
```

And I just get a blank page - it does write out the right data though, just not the rest of the page

Hi, I am using flexigrid, and im posting parameters to from flexigrid.js to a php script to return json to the grid.
Flexigrid allows me to sort, filter etc. just as jquery should allow.

I want to catch the last posted parameters to flexigrid so that I can build a csv to allow download of the same (full) information.

However, flexigrid wont allow me to access the posted parameters.

Is this because flexigrid script keeps all those parameters in its own scope? I notice a variable/object called sitems inside firebug that basically has all the info I need, but javascript wont let me access it. Is there any way to access parameters sent to flexigrid? any help is much appreciated.

Cheers Ke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm not familiar with [flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/) but taking a quick peak at [the source](http://www.flexigrid.info/flexigrid.js) used on their homepage, it uses jQuery's `$.ajax` to make the requests to your PHP backend. So although the flexigrid API may not allow you to discover the parameters that it is posting, you can use the hooks that jQuery provides (the [global ajax events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)) to monitor what is going on. In particular, [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) will give you the info you want once the flexigrid request to your backend has returned successfully, at which point you can use the data that was posted to build your CSV link.

Try pasting this into the firebug console while on the [flexigrid homepage](http://www.flexigrid.info/), running it and then clicking a column header in the Example 3 (Flexigrid with a dynamic data):

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(
    function(ev, xhr, options) {
        console.info(options.data);
    }
);
```

You should see the `data` value that was used in the `$.ajax` request made by the flexegrid in your console output. e.g.

```
page=1&rp=15&sortname=printable_name&sortorder=asc&query=&qtype=name
```

Comment: this gets me nearly on my way, thanku, but how do i turn this into a variable so i can use it in my html url?

Comment: cheers m8 i got there in the end and this one pointed me in the right direction, :)